# Jscroll not working on android device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a weird problem with [this](http://jscroll.com) infinite scroll plugin.

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.pagination').hide();
    $('.scroll').jscroll({
        loadingHtml: '<div class="loading-icon"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-2x fa-spin text-muted"></i></div>',
        autoTrigger: true,
        nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
        contentSelector: 'div.scroll',
        callback: function() {
            $('ul.pagination').remove();

            //Some extra code for lazyload and emoji
            $("img.lazy").lazyload({
                effect: "fadeIn",
            });
            $(".emojizone").each(function() {
                var original = $(this).html();
                var converted = emojione.toImage(original);
                $(this).html(converted);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The infinite works like a charm on laptop or desktop devices, but on mobile device it doesn't seems to work.

**Full story:**
On the first load on mobile device, when I scroll to the end of the page, the next page has to be loaded. But it doesn't. But when I minimize my mobile browser and return back to it, the next page is loaded(Weird but works)
Again when the end of the page is reached, I have to minimize the browser and maximize it again to get the next page loaded with infinite scroll.

I am using `XAMPP` for localhost development and using `Chrome on Android` for mobile testing.

**Update:**
This is the html part which is dynamically changed into infinite scroll with the above jQuery

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li>
    <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/awesome-images/public/home?page=2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/awesome-images/public/home?page=3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/awesome-images/public/home?page=4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/awesome-images/public/home?page=2" rel="next">»</a></li>
</ul>
```

This code is present at the end of the page.

Comment: Please share HTML also

Comment: @NidhinChandran I have updated the question.

Comment: many custom scroll plugins doesn't work on mobiles and I don't thing You can fix it without customize plugin script.

Answer (score 2):

jScroll has a `padding` option that allows you to set the distance from the bottom of the page at which to start loading the next set of content. Initialize with this as something above the default value of `0` to trigger the auto-load sooner and it will fix your issue on mobile.

```js
$('.jscroll').jscroll({
    loadingHtml: '<img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" /> Loading...',
    padding: 20,
    nextSelector: 'a.jscroll-next:last',
    contentSelector: 'li'
});
```

Full options list here:
https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll#options

Answer (score 0):

You need open jscroll.js and change this line

```
c = Math.ceil(r - i + f.height()+ o);
```

to

```
c = Math.ceil(r - i + f.height()+200 + o);
```

So it starts loading before end of page.